# Mathematica exponentiation and finding a specified coefficient

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, discrete-mathematics

I have the following code, and it does exactly what I want it to do, except that it is ridiculously slow. I would not be so bothered, except that when I process the code "manually", i.e., I break it into parts and do them individually, it's near instantaneous.

Here is my code:

```
Coefficient[Product[Sum[x^(j*Prime[i]), {j, 0, Floor[q/Prime[i]]}], 
                        {i, 1, PrimePi[q]}], x, q]
```

Picture added for clarity:

[image]

I think it is trying to optimize the sum, but am not sure. Is there a way to stop that?

In addition, since all my coefficients are positive, and I only want the x^qth one, is there a way to get Mathematica to discard all exponents that are larger than that and not do all the multiplication with those?

Comment: @George It seems life more of a programming thing, and I dont want to be accused of double posting... What do I do?

Comment: Please give the *Mathematica* code instead of Latex code for the formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you want but, as the coefficient will depend on `q`, I assume you want it evaluated for specific `q`. Since I suspected (like you) that the time is taken to optimise the produt and sum, I rewrote it. You had something like:

```
With[{q = 80}, Coefficient[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(PrimePi[q]\)]\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(\[LeftFloor]
\*FractionBox[\(q\), \(Prime[i]\)]\[RightFloor]\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(j*Prime[i]\)])\)\), x, q]] // Timing
(*
-> {8.36181, 10003}
*)
```

which I rewrote with purely structural operations as

```
With[{q = 80},
 Coefficient[Times @@ 
 Table[Plus @@ Table[x^(j*Prime[i]), {j, 0, Floor[q/Prime[i]]}],
        {i, 1, PrimePi[q]}], x, q]] // Timing
(*
-> {8.36357, 10003}
*)
```

(this just builds up a list of the terms and then multiplies them, so no symbolic analysis is performed).

Just building up the polynomial is instantaneous, but it has a few thousand terms, so what is probably happening is that `Coefficient` spends a lot of time to make sure it has the right coefficient. Actually you can solve this by `Expand`ing the polynomial. Thus:

```
 With[{q = 80}, Coefficient[Expand[\!\(
 \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Product]\), \(i = 1\), \(PrimePi[q]\)]\((
 \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(\[LeftFloor]
 \*FractionBox[\(q\), \(Prime[i]\)]\[RightFloor]\)]
 \*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(j*Prime[i]\)])\)\)], x, q]] // Timing
 (*
 -> {0.240862, 10003}
 *)
```

and it also works for my method.

So to summarise, just stick `Expand` in front of the expression and before you take the coefficient.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reason that Coefficient is so "stupid"? and is there a way to get it to discard unneeded terms?

Comment: @soandos: (I think) `Coefficient` is slow because it *isn't* "stupid". For large `q` your polynomial in the factored form is still quick to generate, but impossibly large to expand. `Coefficient` will still work in cases where `Expand` will eat up all the memory in your computer. Look at `LeafCount` and `ByteCount` for the polynomial before and after expansion for `q~100`. That said, maybe it can be better optimized for small `q`...

Comment: @Simon: It would seem to me that even if it would expand to thousands of terms, it should not matter, as it should realize that they will be over q, and then chuck them all. guess its just too much to ask for.

Comment: @soandos: Maybe... what if you want a really high order term, would you have to keep all the lower order terms? In the case of your polynomial, the optimal solution would be to only include terms that make up the prime partitions of `q`... see my answer. I'm not sure what assumptions `SerieCoefficient` makes that make it so much faster than `Coefficient`. That might be worth its own question.

Comment: @Simon, I think its because for a series, you only need to generate the term you want, not the ones above or below it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason that the original code is slow is because `Coefficient` is made to work even with very large expressions - ones that would not fit into the memory if naively expanded.

Here's the original polynomial:

```
poly[q_, x_] := Product[Sum[ x^(j*Prime[i]), 
                            {j, 0, Floor[q/Prime[i]]}], {i, 1, PrimePi[q]}]
```

See how for not too large `q`, expanding the polynomial takes up a lot more memory and becomes fairly slow:

```
In[2]:= Through[{LeafCount, ByteCount}[poly[300, x]]] // Timing
        Through[{LeafCount, ByteCount}[Expand@poly[300, x]]] // Timing
Out[2]= { 0.01, { 1859,   55864}}
Out[3]= {25.27, {77368, 3175840}}
```

Now let's define the coefficient in 3 different ways and time them

```
coeff[q_]    := Module[{x}, Coefficient[poly[q, x], x, q]]
exCoeff[q_]  := Module[{x}, Coefficient[Expand@poly[q, x], x, q]]
serCoeff[q_] := Module[{x}, SeriesCoefficient[poly[q, x], {x, 0, q}]]

In[7]:= Table[   coeff[q],{q,1,30}]//Timing
        Table[ exCoeff[q],{q,1,30}]//Timing
        Table[serCoeff[q],{q,1,30}]//Timing
Out[7]= {0.37,{0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,14,17,19,23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,67,77,87,98}}
Out[8]= {0.12,{0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,14,17,19,23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,67,77,87,98}}
Out[9]= {0.06,{0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,14,17,19,23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,67,77,87,98}}

In[10]:=    coeff[100]//Timing
          exCoeff[100]//Timing
         serCoeff[100]//Timing
Out[10]= {56.28,40899}
Out[11]= { 0.84,40899}
Out[12]= { 0.06,40899}
```

So `SeriesCoefficient` is definitely the way to go. Unless of course you're 
a bit better at combinatorics than me and you know the following prime partition formulae 
([oeis](http://oeis.org/A000607))

```
In[13]:= CoefficientList[Series[1/Product[1-x^Prime[i],{i,1,30}],{x,0,30}],x]
Out[13]= {1,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,14,17,19,23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,67,77,87,98}

In[14]:= f[n_]:=Length@IntegerPartitions[n,All,Prime@Range@PrimePi@n]; Array[f,30]
Out[14]= {0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,12,14,17,19,23,26,30,35,40,46,52,60,67,77,87,98}
```